# how to add custom css files in strapi version 4

Tags: strapi

I am trying to add custom css files for strapi 4
i have written a js function which i want to execute after dom is loaded
Css files are added to public folder

```
setTimeout(() => {
      const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      const link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.href = 'css/JordyFont.css';
      head.appendChild(link);
    }, 1000);
```

i am not sure where to add this function. i tried in `admin/app.js` but it is not executing

Comment: Also looking for a solution. Were you successful?